# Mdadm Raid fsck options

Tags: mdadm, fsck

I am setting up a Raid6 Array with mdadm. While adding it to fstab i have noticed that all tutorials recommend using fsck 0 option. Can anyone explain why? Would option 2 not be a better choice (repair & reboot)?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well this hugely depends on the file system and use-case of your Raid partition.

- If for example you're creating a swap partition - it is normal not to fsck the swap
- If you're building a rootfs on a Raid device - you should put 1 on there
- If you're creating some other data storage partition - you should put 2 in the pass coulmn

As per official documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html the nr. `1` indicates this should be checked first and number `2` that this should be checked after `1` and in parallel.